# PHP calculation multiple search forms and tables

Tags: php, mysql

I need help with a project I'm doing. I tried many many different approaches, but I just can't figure out how I can create a PHP script which uses 2-3 search forms and every search form uses a different table + looks if a value is < x

Currently I reset the script to the minimum and I really hope someone can help me.

http://pastebin.com/0cfiHEDb

Which results in looking like that :

https://gyazo.com/23884eedf06931d26ea07b95bc3571a1

That's pretty much all I need. But now I want a second search form on the script which checks the same table if the field "active" is set to true. Then if it is set to true, check if  " Stock " is under " Minimum Stock ". If that's the case it should print out all results.

Then I need the same script to check a different table in the database and print out those results.

Comment: You should include your code and images in the post

Comment: Don't ask for tutorials/scripts. Please update the question with what is working and what's not working to [ask] a better received question.